# How to get input field value using PHP

Tags: php

I have a input field as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="Car Loan">
```

I would like to get the input fields value `Car Loan` and assign it to a session. How do I do this using PHP or jQuery?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use PHP's `$_POST` or `$_GET` superglobals to retrieve the value of the input tag via the name of the HTML tag.

For Example, change the method in your form and then echo out the value by the name of the input:

**Using `$_GET` method:**

```
<form name="form" action="" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="Car Loan">
</form>
```

To show the value:

```
<?php echo $_GET['subject']; ?>
```

**Using `$_POST` method:**

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="Car Loan">
</form>
```

To show the value:

```
<?php echo $_POST['subject']; ?>
```

Answer (score 21):

**Example of using PHP to get a value from a form:**

**Put this in foobar.php:**

```
<html>
<body>
  <form action="foobar_submit.php" method="post">
    <input name="my_html_input_tag"  value="PILLS HERE"/>

    <input type="submit" name="my_form_submit_button" 
           value="Click here for penguins"/>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Read the above code so you understand what it is doing:**

"foobar.php is an HTML document containing an HTML form.  When the user presses the submit button inside the form, the form's action property is run: `foobar_submit.php`.  The form will be submitted as a POST request.  Inside the form is an input tag with the name "my_html_input_tag".  It's default value is "PILLS HERE".  That causes a text box to appear with text: 'PILLS HERE' on the browser.  To the right is a submit button, when you click it, the browser url changes to `foobar_submit.php` and the below code is run.

**Put this code in foobar_submit.php in the same directory as foobar.php:**

```
<?php
  echo $_POST['my_html_input_tag'];
  echo "<br><br>";
  print_r($_POST); 
?>
```

**Read the above code so you know what its doing:**

The HTML form from above populated the $_POST superglobal with key/value pairs representing the html elements inside the form.  The echo prints out the value by key: 'my_html_input_tag'.  If the key is found, which it is, its value is returned: "PILLS HERE".

Then print_r prints out all the keys and values from $_POST so you can peek as to what else is in there.

The value of the input tag with name=`my_html_input_tag` was put into the $_POST and you retrieved it inside another PHP file.

Answer (score 9):

You can get the value `$value` as :

```
$value =  $_POST['subject'];
```

or:

`$value = $_GET['subject'];` ,depending upon the form method used.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['subject'] =  $value;
```

the value is assigned to session variable subject.

Answer (score 4):

For global use, you may use:

```
$val = $_REQUEST['subject'];
```

and to add yo your session, simply

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['subject'] =  $val;
```

And you dont need jQuery in this case.

Answer (score 3):

If its a get request use, `$_GET['subject']` or if its a post request use, `$_POST['subject']`

Answer (score 3):

```
function get_input_tags($html)
{
    $post_data = array();

    // a new dom object
    $dom = new DomDocument; 

    //load the html into the object
    $dom->loadHTML($html); 
    //discard white space
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

    //all input tags as a list
    $input_tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input'); 

    //get all rows from the table
    for ($i = 0; $i < $input_tags->length; $i++) 
    {
        if( is_object($input_tags->item($i)) )
        {
            $name = $value = '';
            $name_o = $input_tags->item($i)->attributes->getNamedItem('name');
            if(is_object($name_o))
            {
                $name = $name_o->value;

                $value_o = $input_tags->item($i)->attributes->getNamedItem('value');
                if(is_object($value_o))
                {
                    $value = $input_tags->item($i)->attributes->getNamedItem('value')->value;
                }

                $post_data[$name] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $post_data; 
}

error_reporting(~E_WARNING);
$html = file_get_contents("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth");

print_r(get_input_tags($html));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="Car Loan">
  <button type="submit" name="ok">OK</button>
</form>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['ok'])){
    echo $_POST['subject'];
  }
?>
```