# how to multiple parameters from javascript to html form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

here is the code what i am trying

```
<script>
 var output = "<table id='e' border><tr><td><input type='text' id=/"t"/></td><td><input type='text' id=/"t1/"></td><td><input type='text1' id=/"t2"/></td><td><input type='text1' id=/"t3"/></td><button onclick=del('"+ divId +"')>delete</button></td></tr></table>";

</script>

<body>
<form method=post action="t.php">
<input type="text" id= ??(from script...)
</body>
```

what shell i do in order to send parameters from script to form one by one in text field? is there any possibilty?

Comment: You want to get text from input text, right? But when you do what? At the end you write in input text?

Comment: yes. excatly i want to send text and place in text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php:

```
<?php 
if($_POST['submit'])
{
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    //Here you have the text in php variables. You can do whatever you want with them
}
?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user" required>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pass" required>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get value from input text:

```
<input type="text" id"yourIDinput" onchange="YouFunctionJavaScript()"/>

<script>
 function YouFunctionJavaScript(){
  var textInput = $("#yourIDinput").val(); // Here you get value
  alert(textInput); // 

}
</script>
```

It is?

Comment: i dont know about jquery. whether  <input type="text" id"yourIDinput" onchange="YouFunctionJavaScript()"/> will work for my function if i create in script?

Comment: Yes, you only do what you want in script

Comment: is it possible <input type="text" name=/t/ value="2" > ?

Comment: the name input is invalid. If you use `value="2"`, when you open your page in browser, the input comes with value 2

Comment: so this will not work  <input type="text" name"yourIDinput" onchange="YouFunctionJavaScript()"/>? so for instance i wish to send value from form to php then what should i do?

Comment: PHP:
<input type="text" name"yourIDinput" />

<?php echo $_GET['yourIDinput']; ?>

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447554/how-to-get-input-field-value-using-php

Comment: so i am just confirming that is <input type = "text" name"/"t"/"/><?php echo $_GET["/"t"/"];?>

Comment: it is giving unexpected unexpected T_STRING, expecting ']'??

Comment: Your name input is wrong. Try name="\"t"\" and php $_GET["\"t"\"].
Or use a normal name like "ExampleInput"

Comment: still same. i dont knoe why.

Comment: do not see the problem, should now work. Show me all your code