# Notice: Undefined variable: POST - strange as I am setting the variable

Tags: php

I am getting the following error: Notice: Undefined variable: POST

```
   <form action="" method="POST">
your email: <br /><input ="text" name="email" size"30"/><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php

        $email= $POST['email'];
        $submit =$POST['submit'];
```

Comment: Duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4261200/342740)

Answer (score 3):

you are missing `_` it should be `$_POST` not `$POST` change them to. it would be better if you use `isset` or `empty` while assign value to variable.

```
  $email= $_POST['email'];
  $submit =$_POST['submit'];
```

Comment: I just mention if he should use isset or empty for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a PHP superglobal (and therefore prefixed with `_`), it's `$_POST`.

Comment: partially right but overlooking something important there even if you write it with `_` as it is you would still get the notice.

Comment: That's because a given index might not exist in the `$_POST` array. It's better to use something like: `$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null;`.

Comment: Then you should have updated that to your question as the way it is right now its an incomplete answer or at least mention why it would still produce a notice even with the change from $POST to $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check with `empty()` or `isset()` to avoid php notices also use `$_POST` rather `$POST`

in php `POST` method values get by `$_POST`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {    
  $email= (!empty($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code in a conditional that checks if a post request has been made, otherwise the code will run on pageload, when there is no post data:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    //you should also probably check the individual keys exist as well...
    $email= $_POST['email'];
    $submit =$_POST['submit'];
}
```

Also, as mention by others, php superglobals are prefixed with an underscore, so its `$_POST` not `$POST`

Answer (score -1):

It's not `$POST`, it's `$_POST`, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13447651/1757964). PHP superglobals need a `_` to be prefixed to the variable name. Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4261200/1757964), you should also use `isset()` to make sure that your variables are declared first.