# php file write arrays variables html not working

Tags: php, html, arrays, fwrite

I am trying to make a website where you input a value to order food. In php i am trying to make it create a txt file that i can view. I have gotten it to make the file, but instead of a number, it simply displays 'Fries: Array' and the 'Array' should be a number. My php and HTML code is as follows...

HTML:

```
<input type="number" name="Fries" min="0" max="69"><br>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$path = "Fries.txt";
$fh = fopen("Fries.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$fries = array(['Fries']);
$string = 'Fries: '. strval($fries[0]);
fwrite($fh, $string);
fclose($fh);
?>`
```

If anyone can tell me how to get php to read HTML form data, that wiuld be great

Comment: There are many knowledge gaps in your code. 1- your not reading any data from your form; 2- you defined `$path` just to NOT use it, since you're passing a string to `fopen`; 3- when you define `array(['Friel'])` you actually have an array at position `0` (hence the 'Array' output). 4- (extra) not using the [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get input field value using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447554/how-to-get-input-field-value-using-php)

Comment: You should be looking for tutorials, not asking questions, yet tbh. A quick google search would provide the answers...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're aware of all of the potential pitfalls of taking user input and writing it to a file without any type of validation: square brackets in PHP are a shortcut for defining a new array. So what you've written is equivalent to:

```
$fries = array(array('Fries'));
```

Also, you're assigning your new array the string value "fries," when you say you're trying to get this from your user input. Try the following:

```
...
$fries = 'Fries: ' . $_REQUEST['Fries'];
fwrite($fh, $string);
...
```

No need to use `strval()` - value is already a string.

And as far as validation, you may want to add the following before you assign your `$fries` variable:

```
if (is_numeric($_REQUEST['Fries'] && $_REQUEST['Fries'] >= 0 && $_REQUEST['Fries'] <= 69)
```

Comment: _Assuming that you're aware of all of the potential pitfalls_, judging by the number / types of mistakes, I wouldn't go anywhere near that assumption.

Comment: Php will not do the type conversion for you, it will already be a string (even with `type="number"`). And `$_REQUEST['fries']` is an _Undefined index: fries_ notice (it should be `Fries`).

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="number" name="fries" min="0" max="69"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$path = "Fries.txt";
$fh = fopen($path, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

$string = 'Fries: '. filter_input(INPUT_POST,'fries');
fwrite($fh, $string);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: Although that fixes the problem causing 'Array' output, It doesn't read form data...

Comment: All it did was say 'Fries: Fries'

Comment: Here is a complete answer instead.

Comment: It only displays 'Fries: ' there is no number, how do i use a variable from HTML to PHP?

Comment: I also have a bunch of different input values but i just need the fries thing to work first. I have that <form> stuff.

Comment: You will have the form data in the `$_POST` variable. If you want to access a specific input and want to filter the variable, you can use `filter_input(INPUT_POST,'fries');` to access the submitted data of `<input name="fries">`