# How to get input field value in a variable for a link using PHP

Tags: php

I found this topic:

[How to get input field value using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447554/how-to-get-input-field-value-using-php)

But it didn't help to me. I didn't have any form just this:

```
echo '<input required  type = "number" name = "db" value="1" /><br>';
```

And I want this input type value store in a variable if I hit a link it should send this checkbox data as well and open the href with these values.

Like ?buy=#product_id&quantity=#insert_value_here

Now it sends only the product_id and the quantity value is empty.

Comment: Can you show us the full code? The HTML part + PHP part?

Comment: If you want to dynamically modify a *link* (ie. an `<a>` tag), you'll need some javascript code for that, as php runs on the server side, not on the client. To acheive this in php, you will need a form to submit, then redirect the user to the proper url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a form shown below that will submit to a url and it will add buy=#product_id&quantity=#insert_value_here so you can access those variables in php using. $_GET['buy'] and $_GET['quantity']

This is in the javascript console after submitting using the SO snippet:
[image]

You'll need to do some validation to ensure the values are set and that they are the proper type of info. Also, post would be better than get, and using a nonce would help prevent unwanted multiple submissions...

```html
<form action="http://www.google.com" method="get" name="add-to-cart">
  <select name="buy">
    <option value="1">Product One</option>
    <option value="2">Product Two</option>
    <option value="3">Product Three</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" name="quantity" max="10" min="0" step="1" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```