# Need help. Sending GET request from multiple 'inputs'

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a webpage, that allows user to input values, then send to 192.168.1.101:8081 via GET request.

```js
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".sendButton").click(function()
        {
            var a = $(this).attr('value'); 
            var b = $(this).attr('value');
            $.get("http://192.168.1.101:8081/", {valueA=a}, "&" , {valueB=b});
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/action_page.php">
    <fieldset>
        <legend><b><font size="4">Reference Points:</font></b></legend>
        Value A:<br>
        <input type="text" value="">
        <br>
        <legend><b><font size="4">Reference Points:</font></b></legend>
        Value B:<br>
        <input type="text" value="">
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <br><input type="submit" class="sendButton" value=" SEND "/b>  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I know there're syntax errors. Because I know nothing about html and javascript, and only basic of php, so please excuse me.

So, when the "SEND" button is clicked, the 192.168.1.101:8081 will receive a the values from the inputs in the webpage. How? please help. Thanks

Comment: All i was asking was to precise your question, i don't think i am ruining the community for that. This is almost a copy/paste message that people has to say everyday, because we see so many people that don't even bother to do research. No matter what amount of research you did, it was not obvious you made any from your question. Have a good day, and don't take it personnally!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in the right path.

I'd suggest you to use the submit event instead:
https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Also USE AJAX, it takes care of asynchronous calls to the server.

Add an **id attribute** to your form and do something like this:

**data: $(this).serialize()** will take care of getting all the input values.

```
$('#you-form-id').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var path = "http://192.168.1.101:8081/";
    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('div#ajax-results').html(data.output);
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you, clear explanation! And didnt know AJAX can take care of asynchronous calls. I know what to do next. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

**Using $_GET method:**

```
<form name="form" action="" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="Car Loan">
</form>
```

To show the value:

```
<?php echo $_GET['subject']; ?>
```

**Using $_POST method:**

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="Car Loan">
</form>
```

To show the value:

```
<?php echo $_POST['subject']; ?>
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447554/how-to-get-input-field-value-using-php)

**Here is an example of passing data through URL within a site**

```
<a href='page2.php?id=2489&user=tom'>link to page2</a>
```

[reference 2, Passing variables with data between pages using URL](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/variables2.php)

Comment: I miss out putting the "method", thank you for pointing it out. And thanks for asking me to use the "echo", useful for debugging.