# PHP Get Data From Firebird

Tags: php, mysql, firebird, interbase

my question is updating. my new question is this;

```
  <?php

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT');

    header('Cache-Control:public, max-age=100');

    if ($db = ibase_connect('111.222.333.444:C:\xx\xx\xx\xx\xx\xx.FDB', 'SYSDBA',
      'masterkey')) {



        $sql = "select * from STOK where barkodu='$barkodu'";

        $query =  ibase_prepare($sql);
        $rs=ibase_execute($query);


        if($row = ibase_fetch_row($rs)){

        $stok_adi = $row[2];

        $sonuc->stok_adi = $stok_adi;

      }

        ibase_close($db);

      } 
      else {
        $sonuc->durum = "cevapyok";
        }
      echo json_encode($sonuc);


    ibase_free_query($query);
    ibase_free_result($rs);
 ?>
```

There is my codes, its working normally with;

```
$sql = "select * from STOK";
```

But i want this;

```
$sql = "select * from STOK where barkodu='$barkodu'";
```

How can i get `$barkodu` with http post from external ?
Thanks.

By the way;
i have changed my ip adress with `111.222.333.444`
and my database location with `C:\xx\xx\xx\xx\xx\xx.FDB`
for my safety

Comment: Your question is far too broad and expects us to do the work for you. Start with reading https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.ibase.php and then transform your code to do the equivalent using `ibase`. If you get stuck, ask a specific question.

Comment: i already transformed my codes, i have a php file with written ibase codes, i just only need how can i get variable string with http get. " $barkodu "

Comment: Then you should edit your question, show what you did with Firebird, and describe the problem in more detail. If you use Firebird properly, then you use parameterized queries, and then escaping should not be necessary.

Comment: edited, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning: I don't normally program in PHP, this answer is based on reading the documentation and my knowledge of Firebird.

Your current code is unsafe and vulnerable to SQL injection. Instead of using string interpolation to put your value directly into the query string, you should use a parameterized query instead.

That is, you need to change your code to:

```
$sql = "select * from STOK where barkodu=?";

$query = ibase_prepare($sql);
$rs = ibase_execute($query, $barkodu);
```

Or, given you're not reusing the query:

```
$sql = "select * from STOK where barkodu=?";
$rs = ibase_query($sql, $barkodu);
```

See also

- [ibase_prepare](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-prepare.php)
- [ibase_execute](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-execute.php)
- [ibase_query](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-query.php)

If your question instead is how to get the parameter from a form post, then I suggest you look at [How to get input field value using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447554/how-to-get-input-field-value-using-php), or search for a tutorial on how to get form values using PHP; however that is a problem not directly related to Firebird (nor MySQL).

Comment: $rs = ibase_execute($query, $barkodu);
Right thanks , but i also some more with your code