# How to count the number of values entered in html input element?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am working on html form present in a php file as shown below in which I want to count the entered html input values.

**Php/HTML Code:**

```
<form method="post" style="display: inline-block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: left;">

   <div style ="display:flex; align-items: baseline;">
      Articles (EN) &nbsp;
      <input type="text" name="articles_id_en" style="width: 30%;height: 22px;" value="<?php if($data->{"articles_id_en"}<>''){echo $data->{"articles_id_en"};} ?>">
      &nbsp; Articles (FR) &nbsp;
      <input type="text" name="articles_id_fr" style="width: 30%;height: 22px;" value="<?php if($data->{"articles_id_fr"}<>''){echo $data->{"articles_id_fr"};} ?>"><br>
   </div>

   <div style ="display:flex; align-items: baseline;"> 
      Articles Entered (EN) &nbsp;
      <input type="text"style="width: 30%;height: 22px;" value="<?php $values = $_REQUEST['articles_id_en'];  $delimiter = ','; $valuesCount = count(explode($delimiter, $values)); echo "Values Count: " . $valuesCount . "<br>" . PHP_EOL; ?>">
      &nbsp; Articles (FR) &nbsp;
      <input type="text" name="articles_id_fr" style="width: 30%;height: 22px;" value="<?php if($data->{"articles_id_fr"}<>''){echo $data->{"articles_id_fr"};} ?>"><br>
   </div>

   <div>
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
   </div>

</form>
```

On hitting save, **its get saved in a JSON** as shown below with their list of values entered. At this moment, I have entered `149968, 149939, 149883, 149877, 149876, 149847, 154303` values so in **JSON** its showing like this:

`{"articles_id_en":"149968, 149939, 149883, 149877, 149876, 149847, 154303"}`

Below is the section of the screenshot of the form belonging to the above html/php code:

[image]

After entering the values, it display like this:

[image]

Following is the html code on inspect:

```
<input type="text" name="articles_id_en" style="width: 30%;height: 22px;" value=" 14996, 14993, 14988, 14987, 14987, 14984, 15430">
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what php code I need to add so that I can get the count of input values entered.

Comment: You haven't shown enough code for us to be able to help you

Comment: @Andreas I have modified my question. Before, I didn't provide much information

Comment: Just to be clear, when you submit the `$_POST['articles_id_en']` is converted to json? If you `echo $_POST['articles_id_en'];` you get `{"articles_id_en":"149968, 149939, 149883, 149877, 149876, 149847, 154303"}`?

Comment: Hi, it’s get saved in a json file.

Comment: This is getting nowhere. Too much unknown for us to be able to help you. You should go read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Voting close now.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="articles_id_en" style="width: 30%;height: 22px;" value=" 14996, 14993, 14988, 14987, 14987, 14984, 15430">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['articles_id_en'])) {
    $values = $_REQUEST['articles_id_en'];
    $delimiter = ',';
    $valuesAsArray = explode($delimiter, $values);
    $valuesCount = count($valuesAsArray);
} else {
    $valuesCount = 0;
}

echo "Values Count: " . $valuesCount . "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
```

1. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447554/how-to-get-input-field-value-using-php) about getting values from form
2. PHP function [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) creates an array from the value="value1, value2" string that you get with `$_GET['articles_id_en'];`. The explode function creates an array with one entry per value that is separated with `$delimiter` character. Note that if values entered into form's input are separated with different character than `,` the solution will not work because `explode` looks for a specific character to divide a single string into multiple ones that it places inside an array.
3. `count()` just gives an integer number of items that it has between its `()` so if the array that is returned by `explode()` has 5 elements it will give an integer = 5.

result:

[image]

and after hitting submit:

[image]

Comment: Please explain how this works and *why* this works?

Comment: @Martin  I have tried your code but I am getting the value `1` everytime. Its counting `1` everytime

Comment: add this line at the top of script `var_dump($_REQUEST['articles_id_en']);` and post it result after filling form with your values and sending.

Comment: @flash please try updated version of answer with $_REQUEST

Comment: Still getting 1

Comment: @Jimmix I pasted this script `var_dump($_REQUEST['articles_id_en']);` above and I am getting `NULLVALUES`

Comment: @flash see updated answer that works well paste it as your index.php and it will work.

Comment: @Jimmix I think, my question doesn't have enough details. I will be updating it to give you more information.

Comment: @Jimmix i have modified my question. Let me know if the information is enough

Answer (score 0):

First, convert your value data in an array using `explode()` and then count it using `count()`.

```
   if(isset($_POST['articles_id_en'])){
        $value = $_POST['articles_id_en'];
        $myArray = explode(',', $value);
        echo $count_numbers = count($myArray);
    }else{
        echo "Form not submitted yet";
    }
```

Comment: I have modified my question. Before, I didn't provide much information

Answer (score 0):

Here, we can also try and use `preg_match_all` that might work:

Notes:

1. We need to make sure, that each entry consists of valid digits, using i.e. this regex `/([0-9]+)/m`
2. However, it might be also the case where an entry contains a non-digit value in between, such as `149a93`, in this case, we have to adjust our regex to overcome this problem by using word boundry, like so `/(\b[0-9]+\b)/m`

Then, our code might look like:

```php
if(isset($_REQUEST['articles_id_en'])) {
    $values = $_REQUEST['articles_id_en'];
    $re = '/(\b[0-9]+\b)/m';
    preg_match_all($re, $values, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
    $count = sizeof($matches);
    echo $count;
}
```

**Demos**

- Regex: https://regex101.com/r/afKiC9/2
- PHP: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/07a370a52eb6c8d10cdbde9e2427af839a4a988a